# Detecting which shift or shifts an employee has worked in

Tags: php, time

I am trying to make an employee management system where an employee can get inside and enter which date they have worked, from what time to what time (e.g. 10:00 to 18:00) and stuff like that.

So the tricky part is that in my work, there are shifts where the salary changes. Like a morning shift (00:00 to 06:00), noon shift (06:00 to 17:00) and a night shift (17:00 to 00:00).

So by that, I want to make a PHP system which automatically detects which “salary rate” their time is in.

I have tried a lot of ways, like:

```
<?php
  $timeStart = $_POST["timeStart"];
  $timeEnd = $_POST["timeEnd"];

  if($timeStart >= "00:00" AND $timeEnd <= "06:00"){
    $rate1 = "1";
  }
?>
```

But now I know that you don’t operate with time like that, and it won’t work.

Also there is another tricky thing in this system, which I also could not get to work.

If the employee enters that he has worked from let’s say 18:00 to 02:00 which is 8 hours, it is inside two “salary rates”, which should make the system change `$rate3` which is the night shift to the value `"1"` and change `$rate1` which is the morning shift to the value `"1"` and so on.

So I would like to ask you guys about if you knew how to make this whole thing work.

Comment: What format are the times in?

Comment: Try PHP's strtotime function for better comparisons.

Comment: @AbraCadaver The time format is in hh:mm if that was what you asked about

Comment: Could someone please help?

Comment: If you are storing this data in SQL database then it might be easier to calculate hourly rate changes using a Date and Time dimension table

Answer (score 0):

```
$timeStart = date('Gi', strtotime($_POST["timeStart"]));
$timeEnd = date('Gi', strtotime($_POST["timeEnd"]));

if($timeStart >= 0 && $timeEnd <= 600){
    $rate1 = "1";
}
```

The other part is a lot trickier.

Comment: You would be better off just working with the timestamps to prevent issues with crossing midnight (200-2000=-1800 instead of 6 hours). Also using `Gi` is kind of odd because you might end up with minutes > 60.

Comment: @Jonathan Kuhn: Do you have an example of *"working with the timestamps"* given the OP inputs?  Also, how will `i` ever return anything > 59?

Comment: You are right that given the code above you won't return anything > 59, however, thinking of the future, the next step OP will want to do is calculate how many hours in each rate the employee worked. Timestamps will make this much easier as if I worked from 430 to 1215, a 7:45 shift, subtracting 430 from 1215 would give you 785 which doesn't really convert to time very well. Just saying that using timestamps you can get both, the shift and the hours worked in each shift without two different calculations/conversions.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn could you please describe how, as it sounds promising to work?
Thanks in advance